# Does the value of a bigint impact the performance of multiplication/division?

Tags: postgresql, bigint

I need to create a function which takes an amount in cents and distributes it amongst a number of people. I can define a very basic function like so (it doesn't do much but it gets my point across)

```
create table ledger(
    id      bigserial primary key,
    amount  bigint not null check (value > 0)
);

create function distribute (num_cents bigint, num_people bigint)
returns void as $$
begin
    insert into ledger
    (
        amount
    )
    values
    (
        num_cents / num_people
    );
end $$ language 'plpgsql';
```

The problem with this is that if `num_people > num_cents` then I either get 0 or it results in a fraction. Either way, it is not what I want and will break my code. I figure I have two options. 1, switch over to floating point arithmetic or 2, use bigint and shift the numbers conceptually, like so

```
create function shift_then_distribute (num_cents bigint, num_people bigint)
returns void as $$
begin
    insert into ledger
    (
        amount
    )
    values
    (
        num_cents * 1000000000 / num_people
    );
end $$ language 'plpgsql';
```

This way, even if we have 1B people to distribute across, everyone can get a billionth of a cent without resulting in fractions. Then all I have to do is make sure that I don't let more than 1B users register (or increase the value to 1T).

My motivation for doing so is that I dislike floats and I find arithmetic is easier for me with integers (eg. if I know the number of cents in are always in the range of 1 - 100 cents and the number of users are always in the range of 0-1 billion, then I don't have to worry about rounding issues or the *office space* disappearing funds issue). But I would like to know if there is a performance difference in Postgres for running `distribute (1,1)` as opposed to `shift_then_distribute(1,1)`?

Comment: Why not use `numeric`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver mostly because of my bias against numbers with decimals. If I can avoid them I will. Am I wrong in this view?

Comment: Sooner or later you  will come face to face with the fact that 10 cents split amongst 1 billion people is going to be a fraction.

Comment: I really can't imagine it makes any performance difference.  The bytes are multiplied/divided weather they contain zero or not the last time I knew.  I'd be surprised to be corrected.

Comment: Since the question is motivated by personal tastes, it is likely to draw opinionated answers. Use `double precision`, it is supported by the hardware and fast.